# validate a second model in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to validate a second model in my project, but dont show me the error,

Items belong to Compras, and when add a item to the compras, and make a error, dont show me the messages error

this is the view

```
    <%- model_class = Compra -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.titleize %></h1>
</div>

<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:numBoleta) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @compra.numBoleta %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:monto) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @compra.monto %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:comentarios) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @compra.comentarios %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:fechaHora) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @compra.fechaHora %></dd>
</dl>
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
<h2>Agregar Item </h2>
<h3>Errores</h3>
<% if @item.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@item.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this item from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>





<h2>Items de la compra </h2>
<% @compra.items.each do |item| %>
<p>
    <strong>Nombre:</strong>
    <%= item.nombre %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Cantidad:</strong>
    <%= item.cantidad %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Valor:</strong>
   <%= item.valor %>
  </p>
<% end %>




<%= form_for([@compra, @compra.items.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :nombre %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :nombre %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :cantidad %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :cantidad %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :valor %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :valor %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

this is the controller

```
class ComprasController < ApplicationController

    def new
         @compra = Compra.new

    end 
    def create
      @compra = Compra.new(compra_params)

      if @compra.save
        redirect_to @compra
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
    def show
      @compra = Compra.find(params[:id])
      @item = Item.new
    end
    def index
        @compras = Compra.all

    end


private
  def compra_params
    params.require(:compra).permit(:numBoleta, :monto, :comentarios,:fechaHora)
  end
end
```

this is the model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :compra
  validates_format_of :cantidad, :with => /[0-9]/,:message => "must contain at least one number"
  validates :valor, presence: true
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this is just an issue of English not being your first language but you keep saying don't show the error message. Do you mean it does not show? Your question is a bit unclear. Please note I am not trying to be demeaning just trying to understand where the question is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a nested form

This link will help you to solve your problem.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1